# how to create an array from var_dump() result

Tags: php, arrays, var-dump

I var_dump and array and got a value printed, how do i create an array from the result. the array is generated a method and i clearly dont know the structure of the array.

> Array ( [0] => gapiReportEntry Object ( [metrics:gapiReportEntry:private] => Array ( [visits] => 4 ) [dimensions:gapiReportEntry:private] => Array ( [year] => 2011 [month] => 07 [day] => 20 ) ) [1] => gapiReportEntry Object ( [metrics:gapiReportEntry:private] => Array ( [visits] => 32 ) [dimensions:gapiReportEntry:private] => Array ( [year] => 2011 [month] => 07 [day] => 13 ) ))

the above is the var_dump result.

I tried to recreate it

> $nuarr = array();
>   $nuarr[0] = array("metrics:gapiReportEntry:private"=>array("visits"=>4),"dimensions:gapiReportEntry:private"=>array("year"=>2011,"months"=>07,"day"=>20));
>   $nuarr[1] = array("metrics:gapiReportEntry:private"=>array("visits"=>10),"dimensions:gapiReportEntry:private"=>array("year"=>2011,"months"=>07,"day"=>10));

but it doesn't return the same var_dunp value.

Could anyone structure the array for me...

Answer (score 1):

Just assign the new array using assignment operator `=`

```
$nuarr = $first_array;
```

Now the `$nuarr` is an identical copy of your `$first_array`.

You can also use the [var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)

```
$nuarr = var_export($first_array, true);
```

Comment: hi shakthi could you help me to call the last value of the array node 0. some thing like this array[0]['gapiReportEntry']['metrics']['visits'], i couldn't able to call any value from the array, help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention why you want to do this. If what you need is just an array-to-string and vice versa mechanism, consider using `serialize()` and `unserialize()` rather than `var_dump()`.

Comment: hi pelle could you help me to call the last value of the array node 0. some thing like this array[0]['gapiReportEntry']['metrics']['visits'], i couldn't able to call any value from the array or it can be termed i dont know, help me out..

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question at all. Please rephrase.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print out an array so that you can clearly see its structure, couldn't you do the following?

`echo '<pre>'.print_r($array,1)',</pre>';`

I know it isn't using var_dump(), but it would produce the desired result, wouldn't it?